# How do I make sure a keyboard event is firing when manually manipulating an input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am on the site RedBubble.com and want to simulate someone typing into the search box. When someone types something in there is a window that shows data like search suggestions etc...

I open up my console. I type in the following in:

```
let searchbar = document.querySelector('input[name="query"]');
searchbar.value = 'Cat';
```

This results in the search bar showing the word cat but it does not produce the focus or fire the window that typically shows up if you click on the search box.

On google I was able to do something similar with the search bar and then get it to show the keyword suggestions when using code like this:

```
searchbar.click();
```

But I am missing something when trying to do the same on the RedBubble site within my console.

This is what I am hoping to see:
[image: Picture of searchbar popover]

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion dialog window is triggerd by a `focus` event on the `<input name="query">` element. You can simulate that event by creating and dispatching your own event.

```
const focusEvent = new Event('focus');
document.querySelector('input[name="query"]').dispatchEvent(focusEvent);
```

Though, it does not seem possible to show results based on the `value` of the input. That logic seems to be dictated by the logic in the React app.

Comment: Emiel, thank you for this code snippit. It does produce the focus and initiates the popover.

Is there a way to dispatch a keypress event in a similar manner as to how you dispatched the focus event?

Comment: Yes that would be the `keydown` event. And you would use it the exact same way. But it won't do anything unfortunately. I've tried them all.

Comment: Super thanks again for the responses.

I am guessing that they are watching for untrusted events (I might have the term wrong) for that input box. Puppeteer's libraries do appear as trusted when attempting key entries. I wonder if Google Chrome Extensions would do the same which is a preferably option to me.

Not sure if that is part of your expertise but if you do happen to know where I can find more information on simulating key presses via Chrome Extensions I would appreciate any information I can find. I have not had much luck digging into the extension docs or via Google searches.

Comment: No problem! Unfortunately I can't help you further. Sounds like you know more about the specific subject already ;).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the click event is not on the input but instead on the search icon button,

You need to do:

`document.querySelector('button[type=submit]').click()`

Comment: This is close but I don't want to submit the page. More I am looking to get the search suggestions that pop up as you are typing but prior to submitting. I updated my post to show a image of what happens when someone types into the search input box (or directly clicks on it)

Answer (score 0):

you can add this:

```
searchbar.addEventListener("input", function(){
    //do something
});
```

to actively listen for inputs